# Unable to create files in a directory

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, permissions, chmod, chown

I have created a directory in Virutalbox.

Using VBoxManage, I am executing a script inside the Ubuntu VM directory I created above from Ubuntu host OS. But if the script in the VM contains commands for creating a new file, they are not executing. "echo" commands before and after the touch ommand are working fine.

I even used root user for VBoxManage to install. I think the directory is not allowing the files to be created . How can I make a directory in Linux to be 777 to all new files created automatically. I mean, even if I make the directory (chmod 777 dir), I am unable to execute the script from the host. Please help. It may be simple permissions problem. Even root is unable to execute.

```
VBoxManage guestcontrol "Ubuntu_10_04" execute --image "/bin/bash" "/home/cloudlet/Desktop/temp2/three" --username root --password root  --verbose --wait-exit --wait-stdout -- -l /usr
```

Please help. I am struggling with this problem for the past one week.

Comment: Could you tell us what command and parameters you want to execute via VBoxManage guestcontrol. Your syntax is incorrect (in the provided example) and it will be easier to give you an answer once we know what you want. Just give us the command exactly how you would type it in a terminal in the guest OS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is caused by Ubuntu which does not activate the root account by default; instead, you have to use `sudo`. Therefore, you cannot issue commands as root remotely.

However, you can activate the root account as described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#root_account).